# Web Crawling Using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, web-crawler

I'm developing a web crawler Java based. I created a JFrame (Java: Swing). My crawler is running successfully. It's visiting founded link. But i want to add dynamically crawled link in JTextArea but it doesn't. I cannot do that. When i try this my program is freezen. But i can set visited url to console.

My gui like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Lnb.png)

My code lines like this:

```
    Document html    = null;

    try {
        html = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = html.select("a");

        for(Element link: links) {
            String tmp = link.attr("abs:href");
            jTextArea2.append(tmp + "\n");

            if(!this.visitedUrl.contains(tmp)) {
                this.foundedUrl.add(tmp);
                System.out.println(tmp);
            }
        }

        while(this.foundedUrl.size() > 0) {
            String tmp = this.foundedUrl.get(this.foundedUrl.size() - 1);
            this.foundedUrl.remove(this.foundedUrl.size() - 1);
            if(!this.visitedUrl.contains(tmp)) {
               this.linkTracker(tmp); 
            }
        }
```

How can i set visited url in JTextarea dynamically?

Comment: Are you calling this code from the UI event thread? Most Swing controls support being called only from the UI event thread.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] and go through the [help] which will lead you to [ask], this will later tell you to post a valid [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. As is, your program is incomplete, and thus is not compilable, we don't want your whole app, but a simple but complete example (not code snippets) that demonstrate your issue. For example, you can hardcode the URLs and have a single `JTextArea` and a `JButton` that starts the process. We know your GUI freezes, but your question is too broad as it lacks enough information (i.e. the MCVE) to be answerable...

Comment: ... because you could haven't initialized your app in the EDT or you're running this in the EDT, probably you want to take a look at [Swing Worker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) too, this allows you to process long tasks in a separate thread and not blocking the EDT (which freezes your GUI). Also please read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
new Thread((Runnable)() ->
{
  Document html    = null;

  try {
    html = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = html.select("a");

    for(Element link: links) {
        String tmp = link.attr("abs:href");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
           jTextArea2.append(tmp + "\n");
        });

        if(!this.visitedUrl.contains(tmp)) {
            this.foundedUrl.add(tmp);
            System.out.println(tmp);
        }
    }

    while(this.foundedUrl.size() > 0) {
        String tmp = this.foundedUrl.get(this.foundedUrl.size() - 1);
        this.foundedUrl.remove(this.foundedUrl.size() - 1);
        if(!this.visitedUrl.contains(tmp)) {
           this.linkTracker(tmp); 
        }
    }
  }catch(Exception e){}
}).start();
```

The reason you GUI is freezing is because you are blocking the GUI thread. So start your operations on a different thread by creating a new Thread and run from there.
To then get updates call EventQue
It will tell the GUI thread to add the text to the JTextArea